# How to turn an integer into a string in ATS?

Tags: ats

I am in need of a function, say, int2string, that can convert a given integer into its string representation. If possible, int2string may take a second argument referring to the base of the representation. By default, this second argument is 10.

Answer (score 1):

To `tostring_int`. It's available in `prelude/SATS/tostring.sats` and you can overload `tostring` or something if you'd like :)

Answer (score 0):

This works - although it may not be the best style. Please feel free to refine this answer.

```
extern
fun
int2string(i: int, b: int): string

(* ****** ****** *)

implement
int2string(i, b) = let

    val () = assertloc(i >= 0)

    fun dig2str(i:int): string =    
        if i = 0 then "0"
        else if i = 1 then "1"
        else if i = 2 then "2"
        else if i = 3 then "3"
        else if i = 4 then "4"
        else if i = 5 then "5"
        else if i = 6 then "6"
        else if i = 7 then "7"
        else if i = 8 then "8"
        else if i = 9 then "9"
        else "" // can add A, B, C,...

    fun helper(i: int, res: string): string =
        if i > 0 then helper(i / b, dig2str(i % b) + res)
        else res
in
  helper(i, "")
end
```